# how to read entries from a file and search a particular entry

Tags: file, tcl

I have to read entries from a file which contain name/city/emailid/mobile no etc of different users in a table format.these entries are also repeated i.e. eg we have two different names living in the same city

Now i have to ask from user for any particular input from these following titles(name/city/emailid/mobile no).The user choice may or may not be in the file.

It will search the input in the file and will show the result for that input with complete detailsi.e. Name  City  Emailid Mobile no.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. If you have tried something and are stuck in a particular spot, please post your relevant code. If you are just asking for someone to write some code for you, that is not how StackOverFlow works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, you need to show a few lines from your input file so we know the exact format.

Comment: Asking good questions like this will help you get answers that help you (and other people too).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, hopefully I interpreted your format in the right way...

Lets say it is something like this:

> John Smith/New York/john.smith@provider.com/0175113322
>
> Stephen King/New York/stephen.king@provider.com/0157331122

The tcl snippet to read this information into a list would be look like this:

```
## Read the data from file
set fp [open "test.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp

## process the data
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
set contact_list {}
foreach line $data {
    lappend contact_list [split $line "/"]
}

## Read out the information from the list
puts $contact_list
puts [lindex $contact_list 0]
puts [lindex [lindex $contact_list 1] 3]
```

To than search the list just use lsearch on it...